# Javascript, if URL then item

Tags: javascript, wordpress-theming

As the title suggests I am looking for a script command for "if url", then "item." I am working on a wordpress theme that I am translating. All of the content has been translated except for 1 item that is essentially a tile menu item.

I figure the best/only way to translate it since the theme does not support multilungual sites is to give it a javascript condition.

Perhaps I am wrong in my approach but I have been trying something like the following:

```
if(window.location.pathname == "example.com")
{
<li class="b1">
    <a href="http://example.com/?page_id=69">
        <h5>Example</h5>
        <span>Thank you!.</span>
    </a>
</li>
}
else
{
<li class="b1">
    <a href="http://example.com/?page_id=69">
        <h5>Example</h5>
        <span>Merci beaucoup!.</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

If anyone could tell me what im doing wrong that would be pretty cool

Thanks

Comment: you have html code inside js function.. what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: you are mixing php methodology with javascript. They don't work the same and both run in different environments

Comment: It looks more like you should use `if ( strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "example.com") != false ) {...` in the wordpress file you're working with.

Comment: @adeno that should probably be `!== false` or it will fail if example.com is at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe should use a regular expression to catch the url, did you already tried?

```
<li class="b1">
<a href="http://example.com/?page_id=69">
    <h5>Example</h5>
    <span><script>
        var expression = /[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/gi;
        var regex = new RegExp(expression);
        if (window.location.hostname.match(regex) ){
            <span>Thank you!.</span>
        } 
        else{
            <span>Merci beaucoup!.</span>
        }
    </script></span>
</a>
</li>
```

Comment: What would be the regular expression? Sorry I'm new to this

Answer (score 0):

your if statement is wrong because you are checking your domain against the path.

you should replace

```
window.location.pathname
```

with

```
window.location.hostname
```

put the javascript only where you need the text replaced: no need to write all the html twice.

```
if(window.location.hostname == "example.com") {
    document.write("Thank you!.")
} else {       
    document.write("Merci beaucoup!.")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't embed HTML into the middle of your javascript like that - everything in a script has to be actual javscript.  You can use javascript to insert HTML into the DOM, either at the current position or in other positions in the document.    For example, you could do this in your HTML:

```
<li class="b1">
    <a href="http://example.com/?page_id=69">
        <h5>Example</h5>
        <span><script>
             if(window.location.hostname == "example.com") {
                 document.write("Thank you!.")
             } else {       
                 document.write("Merci beaucoup!.")
             }
        </script></span>
    </a>
</li>
```

You will also have to fix your javascript logic because `location.pathname` does not contain the domain - perhaps you meant to use `.hostname` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this works.

```
<ul>
    <li class="b1"> </li>
</ul>

<script language="javascript">
if(window.location.hostname == "example.com") {
    document.querySelector('.b1').innerHTML = "<a href='http://example.com/?page_id=69'><h5>Example</h5><span>Thank you!.</span></a>";
}
else
{
    document.querySelector('.b1').innerHTML = "<a href='http://example.com/?page_id=69'><h5>Example</h5><span>Merci beaucoup!.</span></a>";
```

}